# Payumoney integration for cordova

Tags: cordova, payment-gateway, cordova-plugins, payumoney, cordova-ios

I want to Integrate the **payumoney** with cordova-android and ios. Any plugin is available for payumoney or how could i integrate the payumoney with native android.

Answer (score 0):

While integrating a payment gateway in your hybrid app is big mesh, because its new in the market and we didn't get how can we integrate this particular stuff. But if your payment gateway provides RESTful api's, then there is green signal for you. you can create rest api from your services/ factory `$http.get(callUrl).then(function(reponse){console.log(response)},function(error){console.log(error)});`
and you can integrate it with ease.
For payu you can find the REST API [here](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html) or [here](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html) .
Hope you got what you're looking for.